# Google Spread Sheet - - Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-signin

I am developing a Node.js app where I will ask the users to authenticate with their Google ID's

Once the users complete authentication, my app will **create** a google spreadsheet in the user's account.

1. Should I start looking into the Google Drive API or should I start looking into the spreadsheet api ?
2. Are there any ready made modules available for these in Node.js ?
3. How do I authenticate users using a google login ?

**EDIT--**

4 . What sort of API access should I create if I have to create spreadsheets on behalf of the user, a service account or a Client ID ? What is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To create a spreadsheet (or any other document type) in the user's account you have to use the Drive API

2) There's no Node.js module, but the Drive SDK documentation includes JavaScript samples for all methods that you can use to get started

3) You have to use OAuth 2.0 to authorize your requests: https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

Comment: Hi I did try Javascript API at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart. But there seem to be some errors like, there is an instruction that says Replace YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET with your Client Secret, also generated previously. But the code sample present does not seem to have YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET anywhere.

Comment: You need to get some authentication keys from Google. Have you read up on how any of this works?

Comment: @JamWaffles yes I just read it up at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 and have the Javascript example working, my error was that I had not specified the Javascript origin

Comment: That specific step doesn't really apply to the JavaScript sample, we'll make it clearer